# Why does this enumerate this way?

Tags: python, unit-testing, google-app-engine

For the following function

```
KEYS = {}    
def get(kind):
    "returns a new key of a particular kind"
    global KEYS

    try:
        return KEYS[kind].pop(0)
    except (KeyError, IndexError):
        handmade_key = Key.from_path(kind, 1)
        start, end = allocate_ids(handmade_key, 3)
        id_range = range(start, end+1)
        KEYS[kind] = [Key.from_path(kind, id) for id in id_range]
        for key in KEYS[kind]:
            print "within get() -> %s:%s"%(key, key.id())
        return get(kind)
```

I have written the following unit test

```
def testget2000(self):
    s = set()
    for i in range(0, 7):
        key = keyfactory.get("Model1")
        print "from get()   -> %s:%s"%(key, key.id())
        s.add(key)
    self.assertEqual(len(s), 7)
    self.assertEqual(len([k.id for k in s]), 2000)
```

And get the following error

> ```
> FAIL: testget2000 (keyfactory_test.ModelTest)
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/home/vertegal/work/ei-sc/appengine/keyfactory_test.py",
> ```
>
> line 36, in testget2000
>           self.assertEqual(len(s), 7)
>       AssertionError: AssertionError: 5 != 7
>
> ### -------------------- >> begin captured stdout <<
>
> ```
> from get()   -> agpkZXZ-cXVpenJ5cgwLEgZNb2RlbDEYAgw:2
> from get()   -> agpkZXZ-cXVpenJ5cgwLEgZNb2RlbDEYAww:3
> within get() -> agpkZXZ-cXVpenJ5cgwLEgZNb2RlbDEYAQw:1
> within get() -> agpkZXZ-cXVpenJ5cgwLEgZNb2RlbDEYAgw:2
> within get() -> agpkZXZ-cXVpenJ5cgwLEgZNb2RlbDEYAww:3
> from get()   -> agpkZXZ-cXVpenJ5cgwLEgZNb2RlbDEYAQw:1
> from get()   -> agpkZXZ-cXVpenJ5cgwLEgZNb2RlbDEYAgw:2
> from get()   -> agpkZXZ-cXVpenJ5cgwLEgZNb2RlbDEYAww:3
> within get() -> agpkZXZ-cXVpenJ5cgwLEgZNb2RlbDEYBAw:4
> within get() -> agpkZXZ-cXVpenJ5cgwLEgZNb2RlbDEYBQw:5
> within get() -> agpkZXZ-cXVpenJ5cgwLEgZNb2RlbDEYBgw:6
> from get()   -> agpkZXZ-cXVpenJ5cgwLEgZNb2RlbDEYBAw:4
> from get()   -> agpkZXZ-cXVpenJ5cgwLEgZNb2RlbDEYBQw:5
> ```

I really don't understand why it is that "from" is being printed before "within" the first time. Also, why is it that it allocates the same first few ids twice? Am I creating some weird closure? Is KEYS a different object in the exception handler than outside it? I am lost.

Comment: Not necessary to declare `global KEYS` inside `get`, since you never use it as an lvalue, that is, you never assign to it.

Comment: Tangentially, 'get' is a terrible name for a function, especially in the context of the datastore (which already has a 'get' function, which fetches an entity given its key).

Comment: Yeah, after I had lunch, I then took a walk, it occurred to me that I had not tried running this test in isolation. Sure enough, it passed when run alone. Seems that a previous unit test had already exercised this module, causing the values to be pre-loaded. Bonehead.

Comment: Still, it seems a little funny to me. I believe my mistake was in thinking that unittest would fully reload a complete app engine instance, including loading all modules anew and all that. Obviously this is not the case for things that you import in the TestCase itself. I was not thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like when your captured output begins, the datastore is empty but `KEYS[kind]` has two values already populated. The datastore isn't allocating the same IDs twice, you just have leftover IDs that have never been allocated. Either track down what else is writing to `KEYS`, or just wipe it out at the beginning of your test.

Also, you seem to be passing the actual model class around for kind. `Key.from_path` expects a string, e.g. `'Model1'` instead of `Model1`.

Comment: Good catch on the Model1 needing to actually be "Model1". I seem to have lost my single quotes when copy/pasting. :]

Answer (score 1):

As Drew suggests, you might add

```
global KEYS
KEYS = {}
```

to the top of your test (or better, to a `setUp` method), but the root of your problem is in the design: Functions that use use lazily initialized, mutable global state are difficult to test. Making a KeyFactory class, with KEYS as an instance variable, might serve you better.

What is it that you're trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: I think I can answer the last question: He's trying to cache batches of locally generated keys for a given kind. It's a reasonable thing to do if you expect to generate a lot of entities of that kind, and need their IDs before you store them.

Comment: See, I am actually relying on the fact that this module is only imported once into memory. App engine keeps this module loaded for multiple invocations (request). I could do this with a factory method, but then I would have to "manually" keep a reference to it.

Comment: You could still keep a global reference to your factory, but having it in it's own object makes it a lot easier to test. It's a trade-off.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something is calling `get(kind)` before your unit test starts capturing, or `KEYS` is being filled somehow before things start.

Maybe just add a `raise Exception` or otherwise print the traceback in `get(kind)` and make sure the first time it runs is from within your code.